# Issue with NodeJS installation

Tags: node.js

The node js installation is stuck at this point for more than 45 mins, I tried it for 3-4 times after proper uninstallation of NodeJS.

What should be done? I'm using Windows 10 Pro OS.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjk3E.png)

Comment: Try to download + install it from here https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing NVM first [NVM from Github](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), This can be used to install different versions of Nodes

Comment: Do you mean nvm-windows https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: @GiridharBandi yes, https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases and check under assets section

Answer (score -1):

This looks like you are using NuGet instead of npm.  We need more details about HOW you are installing node.js.  Node does not typically use NuGet in any way.